# ocaml: reading unicode from a file, printing to console

Tags: unicode, utf-8, ocaml

I'm looking for a simple example in Ocaml of reading Unicode from a text file, and print it to the console. 
I checked several packages that purport to support Unicode in Ocaml, but these do not include any mechanism for output. Thanks!

Comment: Probably, you might check [Camomile](https://github.com/yoriyuki/Camomile)

Answer (score 2):

Once your string encoding and the encoding expected by your console match, you can just print normally. In other words,

```
let () = Printf.printf "∑ₖ |ψₖ⟩⟨ψₖ| =  "
```

should work as expected